# Segmentation fault when run C program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb

I just got a error message said that there is a segmentation fault in my program. I use `gdb` traced it and below is where I found it. How can I fix it?

```
void add_to_hash(HashTable **h, char *data)
{
int index = hash_value(data);
HashTable *curr_table = h[strlen(data)];
Node * exist_node = exist(curr_table, data);

if (exist_node == NULL) 
{
    Node *new_node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (new_node == NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating memory for new bucket\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (data != NULL) 
    {
        new_node->data = strdup(data);
        new_node->next = curr_table->nodes[index];
        curr_table->nodes[index] = new_node;
        free(data);                                 
    }
}
else {
    return;
}
}

//Rerturn the exist data.
Node* exist(HashTable* h, char* data)
{
int index = hash_value(data);
Node* list = NULL; 
list = h->nodes[index];//gdb told me this line has error.
if (list) {
    for (; list != NULL; list = list->next) {
        if (strcmp(data, list->data) == 0) {
            return list;
        }
    }
}
return NULL;
}
```

This is what I got from `gdb`

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400baa in exist (h=0x0, data=0x644660 "a\n") at G1.c:129
129             list = h->nodes[index];
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000400baa in exist (h=0x0, data=0x644660 "a\n") at G1.c:129
#1  0x0000000000400afa in add_to_hash (h=0x603250, data=0x644660 "a\n") at G1.c:105
#2  0x0000000000400920 in main (argc=3, argv=0x7fffffffebf8) at G1.c:55
```

Comment: It's unlikely the line you have marked is the issue.  You should paste the stack trace from gdb into your question to help narrow things down.  You should also consider creating a small complete example that recreates the crash.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Sorry, I edited it.

Comment: `h=0x0`. Doesn't that ring bells for you? Getting a stacktrace is a good start but you can debug further by inspecting variable values. There are multiple ways to fix that depending on what the rest of your code does (which you haven't shown). One way is to immediately return NULL from `exist` if `h` is `NULL`. But that may or may not be correct depending on whether `h` is allowed to be NULL when passed to that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line is the error.  GDB is telling you in

```
0x0000000000400baa in exist (h=0x0, data=0x644660 "a\n") at G1.c:129
```

that `h` is a `NULL` pointer (pointing at address 0).  When you dereference it with `h->nodes[index]` you end up segfaulting.  The problem might be in your `add_to_hash` function when you set `HashTable *curr_table = h[strlen(data)];`.  `h[strlen(data)]` could be `NULL`, which is why `curr_table` (which you eventually pass as `h` to your `exist` function) is `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

A call to

```
HashTable *curr_table = h[strlen(data)];
```

returns NULL. We know this because `gdb` reports the value of parameters passed to `exist` function:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400baa in exist (h=0x0, data=0x644660 "a\n") at G1.c:129
                             ^^^^^^
129             list = h->nodes[index];
```